# GoRouter redirect parameter allows going back to home page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-go-router

In my Flutter app for Android, at opening, I want to force the user to log-in. I use the GoRouter redirect parameter:

```
final router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const HomePage();
        },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'login',
          builder: (context, state) {
            return const LogIn();
          }
        )],
    redirect: ((context, state) {
      if (!userLoggedIn) {
        return '/login';
      }
      return null;
    })
```

It works: if userLoggedIn, that checks Firebase current user state, is false, the app opens at login page. But clicking on Android back button the app navigates to home page. How can i avoid it? I want the app closes on clicking back button.

I tried also initialLocation parameter instead of redirect parameter but can't get the solution.

Comment: Where do you get the userLoggedIn, can you share that part as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: the two GoRoutes must be at the same level. 'login' can't be nested in '/':

```
final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) {
        return const HomePage();
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: 'login',
      builder: (context, state) {
        return const LogIn();
      },
    ),
  ],
  redirect: ((context, state) {
    if (!userLoggedIn) {
      return '/login';
    }
    return null;
  })
```